# 2WIRE router and cable modem

Tags: router, wireless-router, cable-modem

We just switched to cable internet and we had to get another router (or so the technician said), but I talked to a friend of mine who said that our old 2WIRE DSL modem/router should work with the new cable modem. He said I still should be able to use the router part of the old DSL modem. How do I go about hooking that up?

Comment: Don't know if you ever figured this out, or are even still trying, but if you are, you can check out this question as I just went through the same thing. http://superuser.com/questions/365046/how-do-i-use-a-2wire-2701hg-b-as-a-router-only/365076#365076

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without more details, which is probably why noone has reacted. Usually you have the following functions: 1) DSL modem 2) A wired switch to connect the computers to. 3) Optionally a wireless access point.  3) A router.  Many things sold as 'DSL modems' combine features of these two, and all do it slightly different.  But yes, on *some* of them you should be able to only use part of the functionality.